# What article to use in that particular case?

Tags: articles

How should I say:

> I would like to hang out with **friends.**
>
> I would like to hang out with **some friends.**
>
> I would like to hang out with **the friends.**
>
> I would like to hang out with **my friends.**

If there are semantical differencies, please explain.

---

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to hang out with friends.

You don't know which friends you'd like to hang out with, you haven't made any plans yet.

> I would like to hang out with some friends

You have a particular group of friends in mind, you *may* have already made plans to see them.

> I would like to hang out with the friends.

They're not your friends, they're someone else's friends. The friends have been introduced earlier in the conversation (you can't just refer to *the friends* without establishing who they are).

> I would like to hang out with my friends.

This is quite a neutral sentence, it doesn't have a lot of implied meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to hang out with the friends

is not quite idiomatic, although it's possible to imagine a scenario where one could  say something like that.

*Honey, the buds are going out for a few beers tonight.*

or "...the buds and I..."

buds=buddies

The reference would be to a group who get together regularly and whose identity as a group would be known to the listener.

"with friends" and "with some friends" would be understood to mean "with *my* friends", as no sane person would mean "I don't care if they're my friends, as long as they're *somebody's* friends".